# Support pure ESM package in my React application to be able to update Swiper to version 7

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules, swiper.js

I need to support [ESM packages](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c), to be able to update [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide) to version 7.
My React project doesn't use [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html).

I tried the [following](https://swiperjs.com/react), written in their docs (to use it without support of pure ESM packages yet).

In `Slideshow.tsx`, I import Swiper and modules like (described in their docs as workaround):

```
import { Autoplay, EffectFade, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react';
```

When I try to compile and run `npm start` I get the following message in terminal:

> ```
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /my-project/node_modules/swiper/swiper.esm.js
> require() of ES modules is not supported.
> ```

> require() of /my-project/node_modules/swiper/swiper.esm.js from
> /my-project/build/server/server.js is an ES module file as it is a .js
> file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which
> defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead
> rename swiper.esm.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use
> import(), or remove "type": "module" from
> /my-project/node_modules/swiper/package.json.

What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: Show how you import the library

Comment: @smac89 I added it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try explicitly including the file extension (.js)

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';
```

I read that this might be important for the workaround.